# Get error "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I tried following code:

```
var contentTag = $(this.options.id);   //Taking id from user function in plugin function.

var strContent = contentTag.innertHTML.replace('id="paginationTable"','style="display:none";');
```

Comment: Change `$(#parentID)` to have quotes around it, like so - `$('#parentID')`

Comment: Could you also explain in detail a little more on what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: `innertHTML` vs `innerHTML`? Also, that code isn't even valid JavaScript, so -1 from me.

Comment: `innerHTML` is ... `<div id="x">Inner HTML starts and ends here here</div>` what you are saying is attribute of an element. you can achieve the same using [jQuert.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Please post some more code and description with what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your dom element in quotes, and as pointed out in comments, inner is spelled wrong and is also not a jquery property, it's a property on the dom element.

You can use the jquery property `html()` instead to retieve the html property, or if you want to get at the dom element you can use brackets `[0]` or call jquery method `get()`

```
$('#parentID').html().replace('...');
```

or

```
$('#parentID').get().innerHTML.replace('...');
```

If you're looking to get simply show an element, or hide an element you can just use the jquery `show()` or `hide()` functions

```
//show the element
$('#idOfDOMElementToShow').show();
//hide the element
$('#idOfDOMElementToHide').hide();
```

Also if you're looking to change attributes or classes, take a look at [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Replace returns a string. It does not replace in situ. I would be surprised if that is even what he wants, he is changing attributes of stuff inside the div

Comment: The question didn't give a lot to go off, but I thought It'd try to help anyway

Comment: He wants to hide the table and not the parent

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to hide the paginationTable.

In jQuery that would be

```
$("#paginationTable").hide();
```

The String manipulation [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) works by replacing a string or regex and returning the changed string

```
var string = someString.replace("someotherstring","yetanotherstring")
```

it can use a regex as first expression and a string or a function for the replacement

innerHTML is DOM and not jQuery which uses .html() as mentioned by others

jQUery has a [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) which works on jQuery elements